# SwiftUI: Involuntary navigation of NavigationLink

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a list of items. When I click an item `Show Alert` I am showing an alert which displays two options: either `Navigate` to dismiss the alert and navigate to the detail view or `Cancel` which is supposed to just dismiss the alert.

The problem is that `Cancel` still makes the `NavigationLink` navigate.
What is a solution such that the second item navigates directly and the others show an alert that allows you to cancel.

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let items = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    RowView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {

    let item: String

    @State private var isShowingNext = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    private var isShowingNextBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(
            get: {
                !isShowingAlert && isShowingNext
            }, set: {
                isShowingNext = $0
            }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if item != "2" {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: isShowingNextBinding,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                ).hidden()
                Button(
                    action: {
                        isShowingAlert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("\(item) Show Alert First")
                    }
                )
                .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Alert")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .font(.title),
                        message: Text("Hello"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(
                            Text("Navigate"),
                            action: {
                                isShowingNext = true
                            }
                        ),
                        secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }
            } else {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: isShowingNextBinding,
                    label: {
                        Text("\(item) Show Directly")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to run it in iOS because on watchOS it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your 'set' part, like here:

```
Binding(
        get: {
            !isShowingAlert && isShowingNext
        }, set: {_ in
            isShowingNext = false
        }
    )
```

I can't define this answer. I just experimented and it works definitely how you'd expected(hope so).

P.S. in Xcode Version 13.0 beta 5 it works pretty well without changing 'set'

Answer (score 0):

Update RowView to this:

```swift
struct RowView: View {

    let item: String

    @State private var isShowingNext = false
    @State private var isShowingAlert = false

    private var isShowingNextBinding: Binding<Bool> {
        Binding(
            get: {
                !isShowingAlert && isShowingNext
            }, set: { _ in
                isShowingNext = false
            }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if item != "2" {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: isShowingNextBinding,
                    label: {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                ).hidden()
                Button(
                    action: {
                        isShowingAlert.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("\(item) Show Alert First")
                    }
                )
                .alert(isPresented: $isShowingAlert) {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Alert")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                            .font(.title),
                        message: Text("Hello"),
                        primaryButton: .destructive(
                            Text("Navigate"),
                            action: {
                                isShowingNext = true
                            }
                        ),
                        secondaryButton: .cancel()
                    )
                }
            } else {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("Hello"),
                    isActive: $isShowingNext,
                    label: {
                        Text("\(item) Show Directly")
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update the setter of the Binding to always update to false and have a separate NavigationLink that navigates directly by passing it a Binding to `isShowingNext` directly.

This is a workaround but it works.